why does it create multiple .venv subdirectories instead of installing packages in my .venv (library root)?
Using Pycharm 2023.3.6 on Windows 11.
I set the .venv directory as the library root, and installed many packages needed by my app (created a requirements.txt file in the main project directory).
When I run the application (from Pycharm), I see that several packages get installed under their own .venvXXX subdiretory, rather than using the .venv that I created.  Why doesn't pycharm/pip install libraries under .venv?
I installed requirements and set the library root to:


project_folder/.venv


But after running with Pycharm, I see:


project_folder/.venv
project_folder/.venv.311/Lib/site-packages
project_folder/.venv311/Lib/site-packages
project_folder/.venv310/Lib/site-packages


/Lib/site-packages  s the only subdir created, with packages inside. These packages installed already exist in .venv)
The files installed in those additional directories, would be requirements from open source libraries invoked by my application.
